# Mongo DB Wrong query lead to connection drop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb

I was starting the mongodb tutorial, when testing the interactive session, I found something strange:

Example:

I type:

```
db.articles.insert( {title:"Hello"} )
db.articles.find()
```

Output:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ee5bd6bc77893733507b43"), "title" : "Hello" }

Strangely when typed:

```
db.articles.find("1")  < - Wrong syntax
```

Output:

Wed Feb 25 20:47:29.022 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Error: error doing query: failed
Wed Feb 25 20:47:29.024 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Wed Feb 25 20:47:29.025 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

So, is this the expected behavior? Syntax wrong = Drop connection with no chance of recovery, or there is something wrong here?

Comment: Are you referring to the web shell at http://try.mongodb.org/?

Comment: No, that's unexpected, of course. Most likely your MongoDB shut down before the second call. Check that it is running. If it's not, check the log to see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

yes!
mongodb-->find()  and mysql -->SELECT
if you search document use this sample
//insert 2 documents

```
db.articles.insert({title:"Hello"})
db.articles.insert({title:"world"})
```

//find the douments

```
db.articles.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ee5bd6bc77893733507b43"), "title" : "Hello" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54eeb06b1cdcaf474b904ad8"), "title" : "world" }
```

//find the first document

```
db.articles.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ee5bd6bc77893733507b43"), "title" : "Hello" }
```

//search

```
db.articles.find({title:"world"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54eeb06b1cdcaf474b904ad8"), "title" : "world" }

db.articles.find({title:"world"},{_id:false})
{ "title" : "world" }
```